# How to bind inner class controller to FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I want to bind a inner class "FinishDialogController" Controller to FXML.
This is a real conundrum.

But `fx:controller="app.view.MainLayoutController.FinishDialogController"` is wrong .

Who knows the correct way?

I search for "inner" in  [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) ,but no found.

this is full FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="108.0" prefWidth="350.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.view.MainLayoutController.FinishDialogController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="textField" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="50.0" onAction="#handleTextField" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="314.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="25.0" />
      <Button fx:id="okButton" layoutX="219.0" layoutY="78.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOkButton" text="OK" />
      <Button fx:id="deleteButton" layoutX="271.0" layoutY="78.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleDeleteButton" text="Delete" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: try with *$* for separator `app.view.MainLayoutController$FinishDialogController`.

Comment: @mr mcwolf 

Thanks for your reply.

Sounds like a good idea, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Is your inner class `static`? Non-`static` inner classes cannot be initialized by `FXMLLoader` without a `controllerFactory`, since their constructors have a hidden additional parameter at the start of the parameter list: the instance of the enclosing class. Is it `public`? `FXMLLoader` does not initialize any non-`public` classes.

Comment: @fabian thank you for you reply,i have solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sounds like a good idea, but it doesn't solve my problem.

What this means? What exactly is the problem?

```
public class Parent {
    public static class Child {

        @FXML
        private Label label;

        @FXML
        private void initialize() {
            System.out.println("initialize " + getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("label =  " + label);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="sample.Parent$Child">

    <Label fx:id="label" text="Test"/>

</AnchorPane>
```

```
public class Sample extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/test.fxml"));

        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When running the above example, the controller initializes successfully:

```
initialize sample.Parent$Child
label =  Label[id=label, styleClass=label]'Test'
```

Comment: Thank you.when I delete "OnActive" statement ,The problem was solved. I use lambda "deleteButton.setOnAction(this::handleDeleteButton)" for now.